# How to send people at different page with mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a login page and there is 2 kind of account. I added a column to know exactly if they are "agent" or "notagent". What I want to do is when a "agent" account is connected, he will go to account1.php, instead of "notagent" account will go to account2.php . How can I achieve that? This is what my code looks like so far...

```
<?php 

include_once('connectiondb.php');

class User {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }

    public function Login($name, $pass){
        if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)) {
            $st = $this->db->prepare("select * from users where username=? and password=?");
            $st->bindParam(1,$name);
            $st->bindParam(2,$pass);
            $st->execute();

            if($st->rowCount() == 1) {
                header("Location: compte.php");
                die();
            } else {
                echo 'Incorrect username or password.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Please enter username and password';
        }
    }
```

I think that instead of header(...) I should put another if statement, but what should I write inside of it? How can I verify if he is a agent or notagent account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the results and do another if statement inside your `rowCount()` check

```
public function Login($name, $pass){
    if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)) {
        $st = $this->db->prepare("select * from users where username=? and password=?");
        $st->bindParam(1,$name);
        $st->bindParam(2,$pass);
        $st->execute();
        $results = $st->fetchObject();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1) {
            if ($results->colName == "agent") { // Change colName to any column that contains the agent and notagent value
                header("Location: account1.php");
            } else {
                header("Location: account2.php");
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username or password.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter username and password';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Here you go!

```
<?php

public function Login($name, $pass){
    // Check in the begining instead of using nested ifs
    if (empty($name) || empty($pass))
        exit('Please enter username and password');

    // Fetch from db
    $st = $this->db->prepare("select * from users where username=? and password=?");
    $st->bindParam(1,$name);
    $st->bindParam(2,$pass);
    $st->execute();

    // Check if no match
    if ($st->rowCount() != 1)
        exit('Incorrect username or password.');

    // Fetch first (and only) match
    $row = $st->fetch_object()

    // Check the agent field
    $nr = $row->agent=="agent"?"1":"2";

    // Redirect to that page
    exit(header("Location: /account$nr.php"));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

Simply use

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/thefileyouwant.php');
```

BUT: this only works of no echo is beeing made by the time this part of the script gets run.