# PHP Mysql Multiple Users Login Form

Tags: php, mysql

How can I detect if the user is admin or customer? The code shown below has an if else statement which is considered to be wrong because I dont know what is the code for it could you please guys help me? I wanted to check the `$confirmation` variable. If it contains 1, the user will go to the admin page. If not then goes to the customer page. How should I do this? Btw the if is the admin and then the first else is the customer in the if else statement.

PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("dbcon.php");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$qry="SELECT * FROM admininfo WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        //$_SESSION['fname'] = $user['fname'];
        //$_SESSION['lname'] = $user['lname'];
        //$_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
        //$_SESSION['password'] = $user['password'];
        $_SESSION['confirmation'] = $user['confirmation'];

        session_write_close();
        header("Location:menu.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        header("Location:menu1.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547216/how-to-send-people-at-different-page-with-mysql/22547352#22547352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add another field for your *admininfo* table and have it here declare if a user is admin or not. For example, there is *status* field in your *admininfo* and your query would be like this (this is just an example):

```
$yourconnection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","NameOfYourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($yourconnection,$_POST['username']); /* prevents a bit of SQL injection */
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($yourconnection,$_POST['password']); /* prevents a bit of SQL injection */

$qry=mysqli_query($yourconnection,"SELECT * FROM admininfo WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' AND status='customer'");
$qryadmin=mysqli_query($yourconnection,"SELECT * FROM admininfo WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' AND status='administrator'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($qry)==1){
header("LOCATION:CustomerPage.php");
}

else if(mysqli_num_rows($qryadmin)==1){
header("LOCATION:AdminUserPage.php");
}

else {
echo "Error! No user found.";
}
```

And try using MySQLi instead of its predecessor, MySQL.

Comment: I have a question, what does the ==1 do? and after testing it out the error was Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\addeditdelete1\loginExec.php on line 12

Comment: It means if a query has been found. And your error states that your query is not right. Error is in your mysqli_query(SELECT).

Comment: And take note, have your connection store in a variable so you can use it along your query. AND! make sure you have status field in your admininfo table and NO duplicate username, password, and status